# Android:Passing arguments to testcase

Tags: android, instrumentation

I am using "am instrument" command to run a test case.

How do I pass arguments to testcase and run it using "am instrument" command?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to pass command line arguments to a test case via am instrument.

What arguments do you need to pass to the test case?  Why can't these arguments be defined in the testcase itself or in a resource file?

If you need fine grained control over your test instrumentation, you may want to create your own version of InstrumentationTestRunner.

Comment: to execute this test case, run this from the terminal: `adb shell am instrument -w [your test package]/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

Comment: @MediumTest
 public void test_Send_maual(String Pno,String text)
 {  }   Every time I am hardcoding the pno and text and running it from the command line ,it works fine.But how can i give those values from command line

Comment: You can't.  And you probably don't want to have to run your tests this way.  It might be better to change your test method to something like `public void test_Send_Messages()` which runs your tests for all likely possible values of Pno and text.

Comment: Dont mind spatulamania I am a fresher, I recently started learning android application development can you tell me how to write a testcase for testing argumented functions.Send me if there are any  links